# IntelliJ can't resolve com.amazonaws symbols com.amazonaws.SdkClientException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, intellij-idea

Im working in this intellij java maven project on ubuntu 18.04, i want to run my project but i get this error message:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class sdkBaseException
  location: package com.amazonaws
```

These are the libraries that i have installed but for some reason com.amazonaws.SdkClientException is not working when im trying to import with `import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException` but all the other com.amazonaws.blahblah are working just fine.

[image]

I already installed the AWS toolkit plugin, what em i missing? i cant find anything helpfull online.

Comment: Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand, i have a typo¡?

Comment: Can you build project from the command line by Maven?

Answer (score 0):

> Im working in this intellij java maven project

If this is a Maven based project you must manage dependencies in Maven pom.xml  and not manually through IDE UI.

Add required dependency into the `dependencies` section of your pom.xml file.

If this is a locally built dependency, then first [install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955695/2000323) it into your local Maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file \
   -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
   -DgroupId=<group-id> \
   -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
   -Dversion=<version> \
   -Dpackaging=<packaging> \
   -DgeneratePom=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the import documentation depending on the version of the library you are adding, in this case for version **1.11.1034** use this documentation https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.1034/documentation.

You have to import all the following dependencies for that version:

```
java.lang.Object
java.lang.Throwable
java.lang.Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException
com.amazonaws.SdkBaseException
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException
```

If you are looking for other versions see: https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php?search_box=com.amazonaws.SdkClientException&p=5